# Which Maxwell equation explains how electric engines work

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

While I understand that electric generators (magnetic field $\to$ electric current) work according to Maxwell-Faraday law, some people say that electric engines (electric current $\to$ magnetic field) work according to the same law, while some others say that they follow Maxwell-Ampere law rules.

My personal feeling is that the latter is correct but I would like a (justified) confirmation from the experts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Faraday's_law) is:
$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E} = - \frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}$$
It says: a time-varying magnetic field $\vec{B}$
generates a curling electric field $\vec{E}$.
This is basic principle how [electric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator) work.

---

[Ampère's law (with Maxwell's addition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Amp%C3%A8re's_law_with_Maxwell's_addition) is
$$\frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B} = \vec{j} + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial t}$$
It says: a current density $\vec{j}$
generates a curling magnetic field $\vec{B}$.
This is the basic principle how [electromagnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet) and [electric motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motor) work.

In addition to that it also says:
a time-varying electric field $\vec{E}$ generates a curling magnetic field $\vec{B}$.
But due to the very small value of $\epsilon_0$ this effect
is mostly neglectable in electro-technics, except when
very high frequencies, hence very big $\frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial t}$,
are involved.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I thought, but I was reading Susskind's book on Classical Field Theory and he said that Faraday's equation as you described it  "is one mathematical formulation of Faraday’s law that governs the workings of all electromechanical devices such as motors and generators". And he is not the only one to have said that, which is, to say the least, confusing...

Answer (score 0):

> some people say that electric engines (electric current → magnetic field) work according to the same law, while some others say that they follow Maxwell-Ampere law rules

Of course, for a complete description of the behavior you need to include all of Maxwell's equations, as well as the Lorentz force law and the constitutive equations such as Ohm's law and those describing the magnetization of any permanent magnets. However, if you want to appropriately simplify the calculation then you can use the magnetoquasistatic approximation which is described in chapters 3 and 8 here: http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/book.html

In the magnetoquasistatic approach we focus on Ampere's law, but with the displacement current term approximated as 0. So we have Ampere's law approximated as $\nabla \times H = J$ and then the continuity conditions derived as $\nabla \times E = 0$ and $\nabla \cdot H = 0$. Solving these we can describe the function of an electric motor to a good approximation. We can also compute the displacement current as a sort of error term to see how good or bad the approximation is. If we do so then we will find that the errors are related to the size of the motor and the frequency of the changing currents in the motor. As long as that is much less than c then the approximation is pretty good.

I find that formally looking at a problem as either electroquasistatic, magnetoquasistatic, or electrodynamic is a good systematic approach for considering questions like this. The textbook above gives many good exercises for building an intuition about when you use each approximation, and what errors are introduced by doing so. It also formally adds the "justification" that you are looking for.